# getDocument by id / get input text from button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, getelementbyid

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#guessSubmit').on('click',function(){
    userGuess=$('#userGuess').val();
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML='Your name: '+ userGuess;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Pick a number" class="picking"  id="userGuess"> 
        <button class="submit" id="guessSubmit"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>Submit</button>         
 <p id="results"></p>
```

I was trying to display the input text and using query and getElementById but my code doesn't work- does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: The code in your question works. Did you find your answer?

Comment: @jrummell, the OP edited the question to fix the problem after answers were given.

Answer (score 3):

You have invalid script:

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML='Your name: '+ ;
```

That will give you an error in your console:

```
Unexpected token ;
```

Your code should be:

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML='Your name: '+ userGuess;
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yyqnhvvf/2/

Comment: Oh sorry, yea I forgot to add that- but still it doesn't work even if I add + userGuess

Comment: @learningcoding, it does work.  See the jsfiddle I added to my answer.

Comment: hmm thats strange- I was doing that on codepen and there-it doesn't work and nothing is being shown..

Comment: Oh and I have another question: is .innerHTML necessary? Because document.getElementById("results")='Your name: '+ userGuess;

Comment: Yes, it's necessary.  getElementById returns an element.  You don't want to change that reference.  You want to change what is between the `<p>` and `</p>` tags, and innerHTML is the way to do that.

Comment: but why can I still see the number, even if I leave out .innerHTML?

Comment: You can't.  You probably just forgot to re-run the jsfiddle.  See: https://jsfiddle.net/1p3Lxo0e/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually returning the userGuess in the last string. Add the userGuess variable to the end of it:

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML='Your name: '+ userGuess;
```

Comment: Oh sorry, yea I forgot to add that- but still it doesn't work even if I add + userGuess